# preg_replace remove special characters, ampersand changes to numbers

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, str-replace, ampersand

I am using the pregmatch:

```
$titleClass = str_replace(' ', '-', get_the_title());
$titleClass = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', strtolower($titleClass));
$titleClass = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $titleClass);
```

I use Wordpress yes, but since this should just be about a string I thought I could ask it here. Whenever I use this pregmatch the output of `$titleClass` replaces the ampersand with 038 any idea how to get it removed? On symbols like "|" it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your ampersand is converted to a htmlentity `&038;`. After you do your replacements your script removes all characters except numbers and latin characters. So `&038;` is converted to `038`.

You can check if it is true by outputing the result of `get_the_title()` function before doing any replacements.

In order to remove it, you can use html_entity_decode() function before doing replacements:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: The weird thing about it is, if the method is echo'd by itself it just shows the & normally

Comment: Did you view the page source or checked in the browser? Browser will display it as &, whereas in source it should be `&038;`

Comment: The decode function worked thanks! I checked in the browser indeed my fault. Thanks for the help!